# Two essentially the same answer: one old and one newer (plagiarism)?

Tags: discussion, answers

I think it's not appropriate that someone just copies someone else's answer. Or even post an answer to a question that is essentially the same as others.

Imagine someone asking: How to do X?
And the answers:
A1: You do Y to do X. (January 2015, 0 upvotes)
A2: You have to do Y to do X. (March 2016, 15 upvotes)

This is just unfair.

This happens in this question: ["Error Applying Security - Access is denied" while changing file permissions on windows server 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/192748/error-applying-security-access-is-denied-while-changing-file-permissions-on/694768)

See Cheng Bo's older answer compared to the upvoted Jevunal's answer. Users should not just paste duplicate answers.

My question: what to do in the case? Should I flag? Should moderators delete duplicate answer?

Comment: Apparently [a moderator failed to pick up on the fact that the answer was actually a thank-you answer to cheng bo](https://serverfault.com/posts/694768/revisions) and instead removed the thanks and left the answer so it looked plagiarized. And someone *else* edited the answer to add a completely new statement after *that*.

Comment: @Pang + Quill, Ah yes! I forgot I was coming from Server Fault. Should this question be flagged to have it moved?

Comment: @BoltClock You can see the post scores `0 down vote`, he should've just upvoted instead of plagiarised

Comment: @Quill: Why are you telling me this?

Comment: @BoltClock, I see! Yes, that explains it very well. Checking the history was the smart thing to do...

Comment: Now Cheng Bo has two up votes :D justice prevails when he gets more up votes

Comment: Someone taked care of it, that answer now seem deleted. A 10K user could confirm it.

Comment: I think it's because I flagged it. I also flagged this question and it was moved from StackOverflow meta... Everything seems ok now :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that a moderator missed the fact that this post was a copy of another answer, with "Thanks" appended.

I won't speak for him, but I will say that in response to some flags I deleted the non-answer several days ago.

Comment: Yeah, I eventually mustered courage to flag it after the comments here. Thannks, good job. Now it feels better

Answer (score 8):

As the moderator concerned, not that it really matters, but at the time I was not yet elected.

Second I made that edit when that answer [popped up](https://serverfault.com/review/first-posts/199751) in First Posts [review queue](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)  where one only sees such an answer in isolation.  As a matter of routine I improved the formatting some and removed what appeared a typical first time user trying to sign an answer with "Thanks".

Down vote a verbatim copied answer, leaving a comment to that effect  and flagging for deletion or moderator attention are all useful actions to take.

Comment: Thanks HBruijn for sharing your experience and clarifying the root cause.